# Is LLVM a typical virtual machine?

Tags: c++, llvm

I'm wondering if LLVM is a typical Virtual Machine like Java's or .Net's or is it simply runtime environment, just like oridinary C++ runtime?

Comment: LLVM isn't a virtual machine.

Comment: LLVM is not a virtual machine. It's a compiler infrastructure.

Comment: I think it is very difficult to compare different VMs as (I think) they follow very different approaches.

Comment: "Despite its name, LLVM has little to do with traditional virtual machines, though it does provide helpful libraries that can be used to build them." http://llvm.org/

Comment: #downvoters why this -1? What's wrong with that Q?

Comment: Well, for one you could have gone to the widely available documentation explaining what LLVM actually is. Even Wikipedia explains it reasonably well, explicitly addressing the naming confusion.

Comment: @smallB: I didn't downvote, but I guess the question is too much about reading the LLVM's FAQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's neither of those things.

LLVM used to stand for 'low level virtual machine' but that never meant a complete virtual machine in the sense of Java or .NET, and 'LLVM' has since stopped being an abbreviation.

A central part of LLVM is LLVM IR.

IR stands for internal representation, which is terminology used in compilers referring to the program representation used between the front and back ends. IR allows the details of parsing a language to be decoupled from the details of code generation. In traditional compiler design ideally front-end and back-end components can be freely mixed so that N front ends and M back-ends would allow you to create NxM compilers.

LLVM's IR is different from traditional internal representations; instead of being based on abstract syntax trees LLVM IR is a kind of assembly language, or byte code similar to Java and .NET. That's where the 'virtual machine' came in. However LLVM IR does not enforce high level semantics, such as array bounds checking, like .NET and the JVM do. Also, LLVM IR can be JIT compiled, but typically it is statically compiled to native code just like any traditional compiler's back-end would do to IR.

---

LLVM has grown to name an umbrella project for many components around a core compiler infrastructure. Originally LLVM was the IR and tools for operating on it (optimization, codegen) but has grown to encompass a lot more including some front ends that target LLVM IR, a machine code framework for parsing and generating assembly, generic object file handling, a debugger, a linker...

If you're interested there's an LLVM conference each year that covers what's going on in LLVM and projects using LLVM, and they record and post the presentations: http://llvm.org/devmtg/. This year's is being held just next week.

Comment: What is the distinction between LLVM and a virtual machine? Specifically, I'm of the impression that LLVM ships with a JIT compiler--in that case, the delta between the JIT compiler and a full VM is just something that passes the JIT output to the CPU?

Comment: @weberc2 LLVM does ship with a tool that uses the jit compiler and executes the result, lli. Although it won't run IR intended for one architecture on a different architecture. That's one big difference: VMs like Java and .NET define an architecture independent form of executable. Another missing component is that LLVM doesn't define any environment or standard library.